# Powershell Get-Winevent Filterhashtable

Tags: powershell

This is a working query i have now.

```
powershell "Get-WinEvent -EA SilentlyContinue -FilterHashtable @{ProviderName='Microsoft-Windows-DriverFrameworks-UserMode';ID=2003,2100;StartTime='2014-08-18 16:01:57';EndTime='2014-08-18 23:59:59'} | where {$_.Message -match '27, 23'}| ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation | %{ $_ -replace """`r`n""",',' }  | select -Skip 1| Out-File -Append c:\TEMP\TIMELINE\TEMP.csv"
```

How can i change it in such a way that it fetches:

```
(Event ID 2003)
      OR
(Event ID 2100 and Message -match '27, 23')
```

Thank You..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply change the Where statement to use an -OR statement, and then group the ID and message with an -AND statement:

```
where {$_.ID -eq "2003" -or ($_.ID -eq "2100" -and $_.Message -match '27, 23')}
```

Answer (score 0):

Filterhashtable does not support bool expression.
Your can take 2 work around ways.

1. Use PowerShell where pipeline.
2. Use -FilterXml parameter instead of Filterhashtable